# Authentication error with bq-auth in rstudio but not within r terminal session

Tags: r, authentication, google-bigquery, rstudio, bigrquery

I used to not having issues on this particular subject, but bigrquery::bq_auth is not working on my installed RStudio. Funnything is that within an R terminal session it works perfectly.

All started when I updated the R to R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31).

This impacts me because I'm not being able to run a shiny application due to this problem.

Does any one knows what am I missing or has any clue where to look for? At least for start, because  I am lost.

The code I am running is quite simple:

```
json="The_file.json"
bigrquery::bq_auth(path = jason)
```

The message:

*Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running bigrquery in a non-interactive session? Consider:
Call `bq_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
*

As a matter of fact, I was just hoping to have the same answer in the R terminal session:

*The bigrquery package is requesting access to your Google account.
Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token.
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to cancel.*

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I removed all packages and installed everything possible again. It worked. Sorry. I had tryed a lot and this last one ocurred me later. Regards all.